# Как показывать объекты принадлежащие только авторизованному юзеру

Tags: django, django-model, django-filter

Как показать объект тому пользователю, который создал этот объект? Через фильтер? Но как это сделать? Документация все равно не поможет.
Моя модель:

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Как мне правильно сделать запрос?

Comment: Через вьюху. Можно получить из запроса юзера и фильровать по нему.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сделал. Todo.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)

Comment: all() лишнее, можно и Todo.objects.filter(user=request.user)

Comment: Ну да, ты прав)